# PL/SQL procedure compiles successfully but does not print out values when I execute

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, plsqldeveloper

So i created a procedure with one input parameter and it compiles successfully but when i call it, it says "PL/SQL procedure successfully completed" but no values are printed

I have tried different ways to execute procedures and none of them have worked.

This is my code below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE vendorInfo (vendorID in NUMBER) AS

V_NAME VENDORS.VENDOR_NAME%TYPE;
V_CITY VENDORS.VENDOR_CITY%TYPE;
I_ID INVOICES.INVOICE_ID%TYPE;
I_TOTAL INVOICES.INVOICE_TOTAL%TYPE;
I_P_TOTAL INVOICES.PAYMENT_TOTAL%TYPE;
I_C_TOTAL INVOICES.CREDIT_TOTAL%TYPE;
STATUS VARCHAR2(15);
CURSOR vendor_cursor IS
SELECT INVOICE_ID,INVOICE_TOTAL,PAYMENT_TOTAL,CREDIT_TOTAL FROM 
INVOICES
WHERE VENDOR_ID = vendorID;

BEGIN
SELECT VENDOR_NAME,VENDOR_CITY INTO V_NAME,V_CITY
FROM VENDORS
WHERE VENDOR_ID = vendorID;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('VENDOR NAME:'|| V_NAME || ' VENDOR 
CITY:'|| V_CITY);


OPEN vendor_cursor;
LOOP
FETCH vendor_cursor INTO I_ID,I_TOTAL,I_P_TOTAL,I_C_TOTAL;
EXIT WHEN vendor_cursor%NOTFOUND;
IF (I_TOTAL - I_P_TOTAL - I_C_TOTAL) = 0 THEN
STATUS := 'PAID';

ELSE
STATUS := 'NOT_PAID';

END IF;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('INVOICE ID:' || I_ID ||' INVOICE 
TOTAL:'|| I_TOTAL || ' STATUS:' || STATUS);

END LOOP;
CLOSE vendor_cursor;
END vendorInfo;
/
begin
vendorInfo(95);
end;
/
```

Comment: If you're using PL/SQL Developer, are you running your code in a command window or in a SQL window? If the former, then Littlefoot's answer will give you what you need to do. If the latter, have you clicked on the Output tab? (There are three tabs to a SQL window, "SQL", "Output", "Statistics"; you code in the "SQL" tab, and any dbms_output  infor gets displayed in the "Output" tab)

Answer (score 1):

You have to *enable* output.

If you're running this piece of code in SQL*Plus or SQL Developer, you'd - before calling the procedure - run

```
set serveroutput on                  --> this

begin
vendorInfo(95);
end;
/
```

If you're using some other GUI (you tagged the question with PL/SQL Developer tag - I don't use it so I can't tell for sure), then you'll have to enable it *somehow*. In TOAD, for example, click the button in "DBMS Output" pane:

[image]